# Why is my command line in script modified before execution

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rsync

I am trying to create an rsync script and am having problems with my parameters.  This is section of script causing problem.

```
rsync -inaruAX --stats --exclude={.[a-z]} $source $destination > "$logfile"
```

Problem is that this reaches the shell as (executing script in bash -x)

```
+ rsync -inaruAX --stats '--exclude={.[a-z]}' /home/brian/ /media/brian/backup/Home/
```

The problem is the quotes surrounding the exclude option.  As you can see in source line these quotes do not exist and are somehow being added by bash ?  I know there are other ways I can code exclude but I would prefer to use this method so please - can anybody explain what is happening to generate the quotes surrounding this option.

Comment: That's just how `set -x` displays strings that contain shell-special characters - see for example [bash - Single quotes being added to double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343027/65304). What are you expecting `--exclude={.[a-z]}` to do?

Comment: `{file1,file2}` will work, but not `{file}` it has to be a complete brace expansion....`{.[a-z],}` will work

Comment: If you try the above code you see that it works as expected when executed from the shell but not when the same code is executed from a bash script.  What I was looking for was an explanation as to why executing from a script adds the single quote around the exclude expression.

Comment: The -exclude={.[a-z]} is designed to ignore any file or directory beginning with a "."